# compare two hashtable values and put results into an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, location, hashtable

I'm a little stuck with the way I want to compare and collect data from hash tables that I am creating. The code is a little messy as I am now getting a little confused on where to go next, I apologise.

I have two Hashtables. Each table holds keys which are co-ordinates. One table holds the longitudes, the other the latitudes. The values of each side hold a location. What I want to do is compare the two tables values, so if the Strings are the same, then the Key and Value can be put into a separate ArrayLists. A coordinates list, maybe one for lat and one for lon to make the gps feature easier, and then a location list.

Here is the code :

```
    public static void trails(String[] args) {

    Hashtable<Double, String> trailLat = new Hashtable<Double, String>();

    trailLat.put(51.7181283, "Bike Park Wales");
...


    Hashtable<Double, String> trailLon = new Hashtable<Double, String>();

    trailLon.put(-3.3633637, "Bike Park Wales");
...


    if ( trailLat.keys() >= userLatL && trailLat.keys() <= userLatH ) {
        trailLat.values().retainAll(trailLon);
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(trailLat.values());
    }
        ....
```

I've only included the latitude part of the code as I would think it's just repeated.

The 'userLatL' and 'userLatH' are the users location coordinates 20mile radius boundaries. The idea is to return the keys and values that fall within that number difference/20 mile radius.

Cheers in advance! Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: *trailLat.keys() >=* What is this sorcery?. Also, why `HashTable`??

Comment: I threw that in because I wanted to get across what I want to do there, I didn't mean for it to be the real formation of the code. That whole section could be a real mess and I apologise for that

Comment: Please post code that compiles.

Comment: if you have a set of items with coordinates and want to filter those within a certain boundaries (maxLat,minLat,maxLon,minLon) this is defenitely the wrong approach..

Comment: Oh that part does compile! But it's not doing what I want it to do. And also, I thought HashTable would be the best way to go for this?? @fustaki Okay, what approach would you recommend???

Comment: Put all these items in a `List<Trail>` where `Trail` is a class with `name`, `lat`, `lon`. Scan this list *once*, check the boundaries (lat and lon within min and max) and add the good ones in another list.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach

```
class Trail{
    String name;
    double lat,lon;
}

double LAT_MIN, LAT_MAX, LON_MIN, LON_MAX;
List<Trail> trails = new ArrayList<Trail>();
//populate trails from db or whatever

List<Trail> goodTrails = new ArrayList<Trail>();
for(Trail trail : trails){
    if(trail.lat > LAT_MIN && trail.lat < LAT_MAX && trail.lon > LON_MIN && trail.lon < LON_MAX ){
        goodTrails.add(trail);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time dude! But I'm a bit confused. First, the code does not compile correctly, there's a problem before the second List...? And second, how should I build the list of trails in the trails ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are looking at 20mile radius, you would have to take a spherical shape of the earth in the account if that radius ever grows bigger.

Also you would need some better structure instead of 2 hashmaps where the keys are lon/lat values. You can use a simple table to store all the points (in the database or as a list of objects).

I don't want to use other people's work, everything is explained here:

http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Good Luck.